# Async in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, python-asyncio

How to implement asynchronous tasks in Django rest framework? After python3.7 async.io became part of the python language and coroutines are embedded in the language .

But I can’t make use out of it i had to use celery and a redis server for such async behavior.

---

### Update

```
class ReportViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Report.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ReportSerializer
    filter_class = ReportFilter

    def create(self, request):

        serializer = ReportSerializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            report_obj = serializer.save()
            #Start multiple tools asynchronously but we need to return the next statement without waiting for those tools to finish
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I tried to modify the create an `async function` that runs the tools, but i get the error that you can't run this function in an executor that's not a co-routine.  When i tried to make the `create` function async, it returns a co-routine instead of an `HTTP response`.  So the `django-rest-framework` itself needs to modify its internals to be of co-routine types.  Any suggesstions or thoughts on how to do what i mentioned in a good way without using any MQ or caching techniques.

Comment: What's the problem that you're facing? And can you show the code that you have come up till yet?

Comment: You should look into django-channels

Comment: @saad check my updates

Comment: You shouldn't be turning `create` into an async function. You should have a loop within the `create` that runs all your logic asynchronously.

Comment: Can you try to run it on your side? I tried this as well but you have to make the create function async still!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with asynchronicity? Django is a deeply synchronous framework and even if python as a language support async functions, Django and it's components are not. You can have _local_ asynchronicity in Djano and sometimes it's even makes sense to do so, but you should specify your problem in details which you suppose you could solve with async. And _I wan't to convert `create` function into an async function_ is not a problem, because even if you get some response it hardly would solve your core problem.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be turning `create` into an async function. You should have a loop within the `create` that runs all your logic asynchronously but even that won't free up the worker process to serve other requests while your async tasks run. The best you can do here is offload the tasks to celery and then poll through another API to check for their status or result.

Django's a synchronous framework and it won't support what you're trying to do here. If you want to have long-polling with overlapping requests then I'd suggest looking into [tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `Async Django REST framework (adrf)`

**requirements:** Python 3.8+, Django 4.1+

Install using pip:

```
pip install adrf
```

Add `adrf` to your INSTALLED_APPS setting:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'adrf',
]
```

Now in serializers.py:

```
from adrf.serializers import ModelSerializer


class AsyncReportSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Report
```

In views.py:

```
from adrf.viewsets import ViewSet

from .serializers import AsyncReportSerializer


class AsyncReportViewSet(ViewSet):

    async def post(self, request):

        serializer = AsyncReportSerializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            await serializer.asave()
    
            return Response(await serializer.adata, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Comment: in `ModelSerializer` I'm using `SerializerMethodField` from drf, and I've to override `to_representation` as well. but I get this error: `'SerializerMethodField' object has no attribute 'ato_representation'`